# Elastic search - text search not working

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I need to search a text content with special characters for multiple fields.
eg:  name_text contains - "Hello , How are you ? "

if i search the word "how","are" i got the result but incase of "thow"  i am not getting the result.

for searching used

```
{"simple_query_string": {
                        "query":  "thow",
                        "flags" : "OR|AND|PREFIX",
                       "analyzer": "snowball",
                        "fields": [ "name_text", "address_text" ]
                        }
```

I have used nGram and here is my code

```
  "settings":{ "index": {
  "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "autocomplete_term": {
                    "tokenizer": "autocomplete_edge",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                    ]
                },

                "autocomplete_search": {
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "autocomplete_edge": {
                    "type": "nGram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 100
                }
            }
        }
}
```

and mapping

```
"name_text": {
    "type": "string",
    "analyzer": "autocomplete_term"
    "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search"
},
"address_text": {
    "type": "string",
     "analyzer": "autocomplete_term"
    "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search"
}
```

Is there anything wrong in my code. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need fuzzy search for that to match:

```
"simple_query_string": {
  "query": "thow~1",
  "flags": "OR|AND|PREFIX|FUZZY",
  "analyzer": "snowball",
  "fields": [
    "name_text",
    "address_text"
  ]
}
```

Comment: hi.. its not working in aws elastic search. when we give any special character  "#","@" or etc  returning zero result

Comment: Please, post another question. For the initial question an answer has been provided. Dealing with special characters is a different matter. Regards.